# How to change to next item of ListView Builder Flutter after choosing 1 thing in current item

Tags: flutter, listview, logic

I'm new with Flutter. Currently I'm doing True False Game, I've followed the tutor on Youtube and it worked fine. Now I need to change the code to fetch Question from API

[An example of responsse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/703Sa.png)

My **Question.dart**

the ***value*** attribute stands for the correct answer to that question

```
class Question {
  final String topicName; 
  final String imagePath;
  final String question;
  final bool value;

  const Question({
    required this.topicName,
    required this.imagePath,
    required this.question,
    required this.value,
  });

  factory Question.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Question(
        topicName: json['topicName'],
        imagePath: json['imagePath'],
        question: json['question'],
        value: json['value']);
  }
```

`The code I use to fetch API`

```
  late Future<List<Qustion>> questions;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    questions = fetchQuestions();
  }

  Future<List<Question>> fetchQuestions() async {
    List<Question> questions = [];
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
        'http://10.0.2.2:3000/api/v1/game/getTrueFalseList/${widget.topic}'));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);

      for (var question in jsonData) {
        Question temp = Question.fromJson(question);
        questions.add(temp);
      }
      print(questions);
      return questions;
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load True False Question');
    }
  }
```

`

Code to show Item
`

```
 body: FutureBuilder(
          future: questions,
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text('${snapshot.error}');
            } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return ListView.builder(            
                itemCount: 1,
                itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                  return renderBody(snapshot.data![i].imagePath,
                      snapshot.data![i].question, snapshot.data![i].value);
                },
              );
            }
            return Center(
              child: Text('Loading'),
            );
          },
        ),
```

`

My question is how to handle the Button in **renderBody** so that when user choose True/False, it will change to the next question
[Here is the first question of the list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lE2Cp.png)

Updated: my renderBody

```
Widget renderBody(String image, String question, bool value) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
      child: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .90,
        child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                child: Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  height: 300,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
                    color: Colors.blue[200],
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        child: Container(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                          child: Container(
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            child: Image.network(
                              image,
                              fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: Text(
                          question,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 25,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Row(
                // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      height: 200,
                      // width: 150,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                      child: ElevatedButton.icon(
                          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                            primary: Colors.greenAccent[400],
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                            ),
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                           
                          },
                          icon: Icon(Icons.check_sharp),
                          label: Text('True')),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      height: 200,
                      // width: 150,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                      child: ElevatedButton.icon(
                          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                            primary: Colors.red,
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                            ),
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            
                          },
                          icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
                          label: Text('False')),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ]),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Can you also provide `renderbody` widget? and have you tried adding the buttons in the `listview.builder`? If you have then what is in it's `onPressed`?

Comment: yeah sure, i will updated it right now. At this moment, I don't know how to handle onPressed for the logic

Comment: here is the tutorial that I followed before: https://github.com/thecode-whisperer/flutter_quiz_app

Comment: how do you want to send the true or false answer to your api? do you have a separate put api link for that?

Comment: I don't have API for sending the true false answers back. I just want to compare the user's input with the value attribute (the value attribute in the model stands for the correct answer to that question)

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to just use the `value` variable to implement `onPressed` which will output a true or false depending on the type of button pressed by the user and use that to compare with the value that is incoming from your API. I'll write you both the `onPressed` functions:

True Button:

```
onPressed: (){
      if(value==true){
         print("correct");
      }
    }
```

False Button :

```
onPressed: (){
  if(value==false){
     print("correct");
  }
}
```

Comment: but I wonder how to show the next question in the list  .-.

Comment: Yeah you shouldn't have built a `listview.builder` for that what you should've done is to change the index number on the button's onPress to change your question.

Comment: i'm new to flutter so that using Listview.builder is the only way I know when I fetch API, pls show me how to achieve that ;-;

Comment: You should be using a `FutureBuilder` for API fetching and onPressing the true or false button you need to change the index or i in your case of the element